# Generate GraphQL schema from TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

I have just recently started with Apollo and would like to expose some existing REST APIs through a new GraphQL layer.

These REST services are already **fully** (Request and Response data structures) covered by an extensive set of custom Typescript type definitions.

I was hoping to find a way to re-use these existing types, and, maybe with a few additional `Query` types on top, be able to generate a GraphQL schema instead of duplicating the code.

Surprisingly this appears to be a rather rare use case? I found many tools to generate Typescript definitions from GraphQL, but the reverse direction seems to be difficult.

[type-graphql](https://typegraphql.com/docs/types-and-fields.html) only works if all custom types are `class`es. That doesn't work for me; I don't have a **single** class but a myriad of simple `type`s here.

[ts2graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts2graphql) hasn't been updated in a year and I can't even get the example code to work.

What else could I try?

Comment: Has the same question. After all TS types are more expressive than GQL ones so it is logical to generate Graphql schema from Typescript types. Or even better - use some runtime specs solution like io-ts or Clojure's spec to generate Graphql schema as a trivial derivative.

Comment: Did you guys find a solution? I need the same thing.

Comment: somebody [more determined, with *'myriads of types'*/perspective of a lot of manual work] should write types2classes converter?

Comment: Since TS types are more expressive than GraphQL that makes it too hard to map TS types to GraphQL types.  You have to figure out what to do with everything not supported by GraphQL.

Comment: Astonishing that this seemingly does not exist? Did you guys find a solution besides manual work? Maybe tools in other languages?

The reason has to be that wrapping existing RESTful apis is the only use case. But it is still weird.

Comment: Technically it is possible, but as you have mentioned this is a really rare use case.
But why we are not trying to build. this tool and discussing something that does not exist. If you look at `type-graphql` somehow it is doing the thing that you want. But technically it is something else. We can get inspiration from that and build a brand new tool for you usecase.

Comment: @John Goofy wondering what did you end up with ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no way to fully automatically generate graphql schema from typescript code cause typescript much more expressive and can describe only graphql entities but not queries, subscriptions and mutations (without using some magically named generic types).

I found not so popular project [ts-graphql](https://github.com/ts-graphql/ts-graphql) that may be helpful for you in semi-automatic describing graphql schema in typescript.

What may be better much way to synchronize typescript and graphql is to generate TS types and interfaces from graphql schema. Popular projects like [graphql-code-generator.com](https://graphql-code-generator.com) or [Apollo server](https://blog.logrocket.com/integrate-typescript-graphql-apollo-server/) could be used for that approach.

Answer (score 0):

[Pothos](https://pothos-graphql.dev/) may be able to help here. It's focused on building a GraphQL schema in Typescript without the class requirement of type-graphql. While you still need to define the GraphQL schema manually, you should be able to leverage your existing types.